# Design Ideas in Powerpoint Home and Studengts

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I have powerpoint home and student lifetime subscription installed on my pc. When I open powerpoint it used to prompt me with design ideas. But didn't see this button in the design tab. I tried experimenting by turning off design ideas by clicking on a little ribbon on top of design Ideas to turn this feature off.

How do I turn it on again?

Comment: Do you have a solid connection to the internet? Design Ideas won't work if not. Also,  which version do you have? 2016 or 2019? 2016 may not have Design Ideas (though in some cases, MS' updates get confused and add it, then later take it away.)

Answer (score 1):

I talked to Microsoft Support. Design Ideas not available for office home and students. I had to subscribe to Microsoft 365.

Comment: OK, so probably what I mentioned above ... MS-booboo that gave you Design Ideas by mistake for a while. This can also happen on a PC that came with the app version of Office pre-installed and not totally uninstalled before another version of Office was installed. Ran into this on my own PC. Standalone 2016 had Design Ideas and wouldn't be persuaded otherwise.